# CSS / Javascript - fadeIn effect not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm loading a front-end site onto Wordpress and have loaded up some javascript files one of which is for a fadeIn effect for the sections on the home page. It all works fine on Firefox and Chrome but won't work in Safari and I'm not sure why. Basically, the `opacity: 0;` rule is sticking in Safari so when I scroll down I just get a blank page with a footer at the bottom.

Nothing's really flagging up in the browser so I'm a little stuck.

This is the code -

**FadeIn.js**

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + jQuery(window).height()
  var tags = jQuery("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if (jQuery(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      jQuery(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      jQuery(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})

  // Have put jQuery instead of $ due to error flagging up in Wordpress
```

**style.css**

```
/* Fade in/out */

section {
  opacity: 0;

  transform: translate(0, 10px); 
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible { 
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0); 
}


/*  ---------------------- */
```

**functions.php**

```
function html5blankchild_all_scriptsandstyles() {
//Load JS and CSS files in here
  wp_register_script ('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
  wp_register_script ('smooth-scroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/smooth-scroll.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_register_script ('fadein', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/fadein.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_register_script ('ps', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ps.js',true);
  wp_register_style ('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  wp_register_style ('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_register_style ('normalize', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css');
  wp_register_style ('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('ps');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style');
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
  wp_enqueue_script('fadein');
  }
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
  wp_enqueue_script('smooth-scroll');
  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5blankchild_all_scriptsandstyles' );
```

UPDATE -

**header.php**

```
<head><!-- head code goes here --><?head> 
<body <?php ?>>

        <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(4); ?>#particle-slider">Home</a>
            <a href="#what">What we do</a>
            <a href="#who">Who we are</a>
            <a href="#partners">Who we work with</a>
            <a href="#contact">Say hello</a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(70); ?>">Blog</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

**Contact.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: contact */ ?>
<!-- contact template -->

        <section id="contact">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                     <div class="secthead"><span style="color: rgb(63,190,150);">&#43;</span><h1>Say hello</h1></div>
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div id="hello">        
                                <p>If you would like to receive a quote for a design project, chat about the weather or send us some chocolates, please pop an email in our inbox, call us or write
                                us an old fashioned letter on the below contact details</p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>  
            </div>          
        </section>
<!-- contact template -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For safari use webkit

```
section {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px); 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transform: translate(0, 10px); 
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible { 
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); 
  transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: I've added the html code from one of the sections and the header.php , the full js code is there for the fadein effect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wait until the document is ready? Also, instead of always writing `jQuery` explicitly you can use jQuery's [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode. Try the following code. Optimised by using jQuery instead of vanilla loop, putting variables outside the handler, using scroll on the window, and so on.

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    tags = $("section");

  win.on("scroll", function() {
      tags.each(function(i, tag) {
        if ($(tag).position().top < (doc.scrollTop() + win.outerHeight())) {
          $(tag).addClass("visible");
        } else {
          $(tag).removeClass("visible");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I actually used a brief tutorial essay for this - never included it in a site before. It works as I want it to on Chrome and Firefox but frustratingly won't work on Safari. I'd tried a couple of no conflict fixes but they didn't work - I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: I've applied your code but now I get blank screens across all my browsers. It's really strange that this works as a stand alone front-end site but won't work in wordpress.

Comment: In that case, provide us with a Minimal Verifiable Example. A *full* piece of stripped down HTML code with the bare essentials that we can use to test. Add a 'code snippet' to your original post. Just the PHP snippets is not good. The output HTML but stripped to its bare essentials is what we need.

Comment: I'm happy to do this but as I've stated the bare HTML works - it's when I load it up on to Wordpress / Safari that I get an issue. Works like a dream on Chrome and Firefox. I'll do a codepen link and update my answer.

Comment: I've just noticed this error in my console - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - can you see what might be wrong?