# Javascript - fadein effect Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm loading a front-end site onto Wordpress and a javascript file that was working fine before has been edited to avoid any conflicts using $ for jQuery functions.
Now I'm getting the error above in the console and can't seem to rectify. 
I've been having issues with making this effect work on Safari as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849503/css-javascript-fadein-effect-not-working-on-safari) .

Here's my code in the javascript file -

**fadein.js**

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    tags = $("section");

  win.on("scroll", function() {
      tags.each(function(i, tag) {
        if ($(tag).position().top < (doc.scrollTop() + win.outerHeight())) {
          $(tag).addClass("visible");
        } else {
          $(tag).removeClass("visible");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And the css for the section opacity -

**style.css**

```
/* Fade in/out */


section {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px); 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transform: translate(0, 10px); 
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible { 
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); 
  transform: translate(0, 0); 
}


/*  ---------------------- */
```

I'm unable to tell if the edited code works on Safari as yet because of this error. It was working fine on Chrome and Firefox. Any help appreciated.

UPDATE -

Console error reading -

[image: Console]

[image: Console error]

Comment: You have extra `}` between `});`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the 4 last lines of your js file from :

```
    });
    }
  });
});
```

by

```
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: To which line of your js code does this error refer ?

I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: In the console? it has this link - fadein.js:16  so line 16, right? When I copy your instruction above I still get the error in the console and the effect still does not work.

Comment: It's getting a bit weird now, I've gone back to the original code from the previous question now (see link above) and now it works in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome. I still get that error even though now I don't have any code on line 16.

Comment: This is a syntax error, it has nothing to do with JQMigrate.

What's the error you have after removing line 16?

Just to be sure, save your js file after editing.

Comment: I've done some investigating in my console and when I click on the link to the fadein.js file it still has the old code - it's as though it won't update the file with the deletion - have you ever seen this before?

Comment: If you run any framework to launch your application or website you should restart it after saving your edited js file.
Also you have to make sure that the fadein.js file you edit and save is the same one you load in your html page (if ever you have a copy of fadein.js elsewhere on your computer, make sure the path to your fadein.js in your html code aim at the right one)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with correct syntax

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    tags = $("section");

  win.on("scroll", function() {
    tags.each(function(i, tag) {
      if ($(tag).position().top < (doc.scrollTop() + win.outerHeight())) {
        $(tag).addClass("visible");
      } else {
        $(tag).removeClass("visible");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the error relates to something else - I've updated my question to include the console reading, does it have to do with the JQMIGRATE message above?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Still I believe issue is in `fadein.js`, take my code & replace with your's, it will work