# Javascript - Google Chrome won't update a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a fade-in effect for a site which I'm loading onto Wordpress. I'm using jQuery for the effect, these effects weren't working at first but I've changed some of the code and now it works fine on Firefox and Safari but not Chrome. What I've discovered is that Chrome keeps wanting to upload the code which I've changed - so the error is still persisting.

This is the correct code -

**fadein.js**

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + jQuery(window).height()
  var tags = jQuery("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if (jQuery(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      jQuery(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      jQuery(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})
```

And this is the old code -

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    tags = $("section");

  win.on("scroll", function() {
      tags.each(function(i, tag) {
        if ($(tag).position().top < (doc.scrollTop() + win.outerHeight())) {
          $(tag).addClass("visible");
        } else {
          $(tag).removeClass("visible");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Which keeps giving me this error in the console -

[image: javascript error]

But it's still loading the old code -

[image: Old js code]

I've double checked the code in firefox and safari and they're loading the new code - and the effect is working fine. With Chrome the page is effectively blank because the page sections begin the process with `opacity: 0;` until the scroll reveals them. Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it might be using a cached version. Try Shift + Ctrl/Cmd + R on the page and see if it loads a non-cached version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - fadein effect Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871261/javascript-fadein-effect-uncaught-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

Comment: @Shiladitya Hi, this isn't a duplicate question. It's the same site but the issue is different - the js file won't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be helpful to disable the cache when DevTools is open. Here's where you find it:

[image]